# Dynamically allocating memory for const char string using malloc()

Tags: c++, c, malloc, const-char, const-pointer

I am writing a program that reads a value from an .ini file, then passes the value into a function that accepts a PCSTR (i.e. const char *). The function is `getaddrinfo()`.

So, I want to write `PCSTR ReadFromIni()`. To return a constant string, I plan on allocating memory using `malloc()` and casting the memory to a constant string. I will be able to get the exact number of characters that were read from the .ini file.

**Is that technique okay?** I don't really know what else to do.

The following example runs fine in Visual Studio 2013, and prints out "hello" as desired.

```
const char * m()
{
    char * c = (char *)malloc(6 * sizeof(char));
    c = "hello";
    return (const char *)c;
}    

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    const char * d = m();
    std::cout << d; // use PCSTR
}
```

Comment: It is a bad idea to write one program in two different programming languages at once. Pick one language. If your compiler is Visual Studio, then you should definitely settle for pure C++, because VS has horrible conformance to standard C.

Comment: Why the C++ tag? Looks like plain c.

Comment: Just for information "sizeof(char)" is _by definition_ 1.

Comment: @TNA std::cout is C++.

Comment: @jcoder Old post - But worth to point that "sizeof(char) is by definition 1" - Is a matter of what you consider 1 - for most machines and most compiler implementations 1 byte = 1 char = 1 octet (8 bit). That said, there are machines which CHAR_BIT will be 16 bit. And in this case 1 byte = 1 char =  2 octet  - So its safe to say a char may be more than 8 bits, or more than one octet, but it's always one byte (Exactly as you said) - This is true for C, C++ and even objective c - And its important to know especially when developing for cross plat embedded stuff.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The second line is "horribly" wrong:**

```
char* c = (char*)malloc(6*sizeof(char));
// 'c' is set to point to a piece of allocated memory (typically located in the heap)
c = "hello";
// 'c' is set to point to a constant string (typically located in the code-section or in the data-section)
```

You are assigning variable `c` twice, so obviously, the first assignment has no meaning.
It's like writing:

```
int i = 5;
i = 6;
```

On top of that, you "lose" the address of the allocated memory, so you will not be able to release it later.

**You can change this function as follows:**

```
char* m()
{
    const char* s = "hello";
    char* c = (char*)malloc(strlen(s)+1);
    strcpy(c,s);
    return c;
}
```

Keep in mind that whoever calls `char* p = m()`, will also have to call `free(p)` at some later point...

Comment: just for fun ^^: `sizeof("hello")` <=> `strlen("hello") + 1` (avoid `strlen` call & need for `s` variable) => do `malloc(sizeof("hello"))` and `strcpy(c, "hello")`

Comment: @Zuzel: OP obviously misunderstands some basic concepts in the language (at least at the time the question was posted). I wanted to stick to the original code as closely as possible, in order to pinpoint the errors and avoid further confusion. Thanks.

Comment: yep, I agree, my intention was not to ask for answer edit :) I usually like to be surprised by these kind of little 'tricks' (language details), the comment was destined to such curious readers ;)

Answer (score 2):

One way is to return a *local static pointer*.

```
const char * m()
{
    static char * c = NULL;
    free(c);

    c = malloc(6 * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(c, "hello"); /* or fill in c by any other way */
    return c;
}
```

This way, whenever the next time `m()` is called, `c` still points to the memory block allocated earlier. You could reallocate the memory on demand, fill in new content, and return the address.

Answer (score 1):

NO. This is not OK. When you do

```
c = "hello";
```

the memory allocated by `malloc` lost.
You can do as

```
const char * m()
{
    char * c = (char *)malloc(6 * sizeof(char));
    fgets(c, 6, stdin);
    return (const char *)c;
}
```

Comment: What if I changed that line to:


`c = strcpy(c, "hello");`

Comment: @sailingonward: No, `c = "string"` assigns the _address of a read-only string to a pointer variable_. The previous memory address assigned to c was lost