# "initializer element is not constant char" error in C

Tags: c

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
char *s = (char *)malloc (40);
int main(void)
{
    s="this is a string";
    printf("%s",s);
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> error: initializer element is not constant char *s = (char *)malloc
>   (40);

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Is your problem solved, Aditya?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to allocate memory in this way if you wanna initialize it in code, I mean:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *s = "this is a string"; // char s[] = "this is a string";
    printf("%s",s);

    return 0;
}
```

is just enough in this case. If you really want to assign `const char` string to your char array, this topic should enlighten you: [Dynamically allocating memory for const char string using malloc()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21579819/dynamically-allocating-memory-for-const-char-string-using-malloc)

Answer (score 2):

You *cannot* not do that.

You can do this instead -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char *s;                    // probably should avoid using global variables
int main(void)
{
      s=malloc(40);
      strcpy(s,"this is a string");
      printf("%s",s);
      free(s);
}
```

Other than this inside `main` you can do this -

```
char *s="this is a string";    //string literal you can't modify it
```

Or

```
char s[]="this is a string";    // modifiable string
```

Answer (score 0):

You assign a pointer to a string constant to a variable, *s*, which is not declared to point to a constant. This is what you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   const char *s = "this is a string";

   printf("%s\n", s);
   return 0;
}
```

In C there are basically three ways to declare "string" variables.

### String constant pointers

If you need a name for a string that will not change, you can declare and initialize it like

```
const char *s = "a string";
```

### Character arrays

If you need a string variable and you know in advance how long it needs to be you can declare and initialize it like

```
char s[] = "a string";
```

or like

```
char s[9];

strcpy(s, "a string");
```

### Character sequence pointers

If you don't know in advance how large the array needs to be, you can allocate space during program execution:

```
char *s;

s = malloc(strlen(someString) + 1);
if (s != NULL) {
   strcpy(s, someString);
}
```

The "+1" is to make room for the null character (\0).